# Как сверстать следующий фрагмент

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Хочу сверстать этот фрагмент, но запутываюсь, так как в макете он для меня-новичка представлен максимально непонятно.

https://ibb.co/zbK3gSh или иначе color: #f7f7f7;

https://ibb.co/sFPzSL3 или иначе color:#ffc000;

https://ibb.co/qx8Gm67

https://ibb.co/hBYv0gd

Думаю, мне бы хватило одного примера, чтобы сообразить насчет остальных по аналогии. Я бы очень хотел, чтобы был div, у него был background двойной из серого и желтого, а в этот div я положил картинки обе и с помощью z-index одну из них поставил за задний фон.

Так или иначе, сделать штуку выше у меня не получилось, так как я не умею делать вот такой двойной background и я был бы благодарен любому варианту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переходите на Tilda, там таких проблем нет

Comment: надо этого чувака в трёх вариантах а эту штуку под наклоном сделать не сложно

Comment: Учитывая, что изображение растровое, т.е. без искажений всё равно не масштабируется, то советую Вам всё же оставить этот скос в картинке. Тем более, видно, что жёлтая полоса заканчивается чуть выше волос человека - возможно дизайном так и было предусмотрено.

Comment: @MaximLensky : ради спортивного интереса только))

Comment: @UModeL да...в условиях отпуска токо - сегодня я выходной - весь день

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не стоит делать вёрстку чисто по макету, разбирая на куски каждое изображение. Некоторые из них делают только для визуального восприятия. Криво подрезанный фон оставляют как раз в таких ситуациях. Лучший вариант - это сделать единое изображение и вставить его как фон. Во всех остальных случаях вы будете испытывать трудности с отображением и расположением элементов.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 15px 250px 15px;
  background: #f7f7f7 url(https://i.ibb.co/Fgn6sF0/test.png) no-repeat center bottom / contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum, porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
```

Есть ещё вариант

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.text {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum, porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Fgn6sF0/test.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Ну, а если уж играться так, как вы хотели в вопросе:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient(162deg, #f7f7f7 0%, #f7f7f7 49%, #ffc000 49%, #ffc000 100%);
}

.text {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  width: 100%
}

.i2 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum, porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <img class="i1" src="https://i.ibb.co/25r2cJW/3.png">
  <img class="i2" src="https://i.ibb.co/zX6wdm2/4.png">
</div>
```

Но, это так себе решение. Куча слоёв, куча файлов на запрос, проблемы с адаптивностью и т.д..

Comment: @Sevastopol' если речь про последний пункт: 1) градиент потребуется сделать для всех браузеров, а это + CSS; 2) сейчас там 3 слоя, которые нужно удерживать в размерах и градиент при увеличении высоты начнёт смещаться (зависит от ситуации, текста и других факторов); 3) вместо 1 изображения, грузится сразу 2. На 4х блоках это +4 доп.запроса.

Comment: а картинку сменить сможете без PS или графического редактора ?

Comment: ещё проще ваще в фотошопе нарисовать и тогда даже css напряд ли пригодится

Comment: продолжайте учить новичков css2.1 и после этого в любой студии о stackoverflow будут говорить как о дне ...:))

Comment: @MaximLensky не совсем понятны ваши комментарии. А в своём примере вы дядьку в чём вырезали? Не в PS? Если бы задача стояла сделать подрезку фона, а не вёрстки конкретного изображения с конкретной задачей в вопросе, вполне возможно, что и я использовал SVG в ответе. Или если бы задача требовала анимации фона. Тогда - да, вопросов нет. А если у вас есть нарисованный макет, слои которого можно слить и закинуть в статичные блоки, то зачем всё усложнять?

Comment: @Sevastopol' если вы считаете, что количество запросов, объем кода и иные факторы сейчас ни на что не влияют, используйте 3й вариант. Я не навязывал никому своё мнение. Что касается адаптивности, "в умелых руках, зная хорошо css, это не будет проблемой". Человек получил 2 ответа на свой вопрос и сможет разобраться с тем, что ему будет удобней.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev тогда надо было в паинте нарезать изображение на три части - и всё

Answer (score 7):

Вот моя попытка на SVG

support:edge chrome firefox ...mobile

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 500 550" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <style>
 
      .fo{
        font-size: 20px;
      }
    </style>
 
    <clipPath id="cp">
           <path d="M0,350 500,260 500,550 0,550z" />
    </clipPath>
 
  </defs>

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ccc"/>

  <foreignObject x="30" y="20" width="460" height="160" class="fo">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum,
      porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquam
      erat volutpat.
  </foreignObject> 

  <image xlink:href="https://findesk.ru/upload/iblock/67f/67f9b1a938009c1fbb050f6b7f32c4d4.png" 
         width="500px" height="300px"
         x="0" y="250"
         clip-path="url(#cp)"
         preserveAspectRatio="none"/>

  <line x1="0" x2="500" y1="350" y2="260" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="5" />
  <image xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/mv4ZshJ/4.png"  width="100%" height="120%" x="0" y="40"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol'  хорошо - будем - но svg ни все любят из за не понимания

Comment: @MaximLensky дело не в непонимании. SVG прекрасная штука и в огромном количестве ситуаций выручает, но, сравните объем писанины в данном конкретном примере)

Comment: @Sevastopol', придёт оно уже очень скоро — это вряд ли)